# Updating QTableView raise : QObject::installEventFilter(): Cannot filter events for objects in a different thread

Tags: python, mongodb, qt, pyqt

I'm trying to update my QTableView when I receive a change notification from the database. The notification system seem to work as expected but in some cases it make crash the application with the following exception :

```
Message : QObject::installEventFilter(): Cannot filter events for objects in a different thread.
```

In my application when an user try to update a row in the TableView, a popup appear to ask confirmation. But if 2 people are doing it in the same time, the second application crash with given error message.

**Scenario :** :

1. From app_instance_1 : I update a row without validate the popup
   message
2. From app_instance_2 : I also update a row without validate the popup
   message
3. From app_instance_1 : I validate the validation popup, the second
   app is updated with the value set in the first app instance.
4. From app_instance_2 : I validate the validation popup, the
   app_instance_2 crash but the value is saved in the database.

**Hypothesis**:
   I guess the problem is that the software try to update the GUI from a non-gui thread but i don't understand why it occur only in this case. (Running only one application instance, it doesn't crash)

**The database watcher :**

```
class OplogWatcher(object):

def __init__(self, db=None, collection=None, poll_time=1.0, connection=None, start_now=True):
    if collection is not None:
        if db is None:
            raise ValueError('must specify db if you specify a collection')
        self._ns_filter = db + '.' + collection
    elif db is not None:
        self._ns_filter = re.compile(r'^%s\.' % db)
    else:
        self._ns_filter = None

    self.poll_time = poll_time
    self.connection = connection or pymongo.MongoClient()

    if start_now:
        self.start()

@staticmethod
def __get_id(op):
    _id = None
    o2 = op.get('o2')
    if o2 is not None:
        _id = o2.get('_id')

    if _id is None:
        _id = op['o'].get('_id')

    return _id

def start(self):
    oplog = self.connection.local['oplog.$main']
    ts = oplog.find().sort('$natural', -1)[0]['ts']
    while True:
        if self._ns_filter is None:
            _filter = {}
        else:
            _filter = {'ns': self._ns_filter}
        _filter['ts'] = {'$gt': ts}
        try:
            cursor = oplog.find(_filter)
            while True:
                for op in cursor:
                    ts = op['ts']
                    _id = self.__get_id(op)
                    self.all_with_noop(ns=op['ns'], ts=ts, op=op['op'], _id=_id, raw=op)
                time.sleep(self.poll_time)
                if not cursor.alive:
                    break
        except AutoReconnect:
            time.sleep(self.poll_time)

def all_with_noop(self, ns, ts, op, _id, raw):
    if op == 'n':
        self.noop(ts=ts)
    else:
        self.all(ns=ns, ts=ts, op=op, _id=_id, raw=raw)

def all(self, ns, ts, op, _id, raw):
    if op == 'i':
        self.insert(ns=ns, ts=ts, _id=_id, obj=raw['o'], raw=raw)
    elif op == 'u':
        self.update(ns=ns, ts=ts, _id=_id, mod=raw['o'], raw=raw)
    elif op == 'd':
        self.delete(ns=ns, ts=ts, _id=_id, raw=raw)
    elif op == 'c':
        self.command(ns=ns, ts=ts, cmd=raw['o'], raw=raw)
    elif op == 'db':
        self.db_declare(ns=ns, ts=ts, raw=raw)

def update(self, ns, ts, _id, mod, raw, **kw):
    db_signals.existing_document_updated.emit(ns, ts, _id, mod, raw, kw)
```

**How i create the db watcher :**

```
class DbController(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.db = None
    self.watcher_thread = None

...

def load_test_db(self):
    self.db = Database(db_name='db_name', host='localhost', port=27017)
    mongo_client = self.db.connection()

    watcher = OplogWatcher(db='db_name', collection="device", start_now=False, connection=mongo_client)
    self.watcher_thread = Thread(target=watcher.start, daemon=True)
    self.watcher_thread.setName("DeviceWatcherThread")
    self.watcher_thread.start()

...
```

**The QAbstractTableModel :**

```
class DeviceTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):

def __init__(self):
    super(DeviceTableModel, self).__init__()
    self.update_field_confirmed = False
    self.headers = ['...']
    self.devices = []
    self.connect_signals()

def connect_signals(self):
    db_signals.existing_document_updated.connect(self.on_document_updated)

def on_document_updated(self, ns, ts, _id, mod, raw, **kw):
    old_device = None
    updated_device = None
    self.beginResetModel()
    if len(mod) is 1:
        updated_device = get_mongoengine_model_from_id(_id)
        old_device = [x for x in self.devices if x.mac_adress == updated_device.mac_adress][0]
    else:  # Complete update from the database
        updated_device = get_mongoengine_model_from_pymongo_obj(mod)
        old_device = [x for x in self.devices if x.mac_adress == mod["mac_adress"]][0]
    idx = self.devices.index(old_device)
    self.devices[idx] = updated_device
    self.endResetModel()

def on_answer_received(self, answer):
    self.update_field_confirmed = answer

def setData(self, qmodel=QModelIndex(), value=None, role=Qt.EditRole):
    if role == Qt.EditRole:

        selected_device = self.devices[qmodel.row()]
        field_name = self.get_col_object_name(qmodel.column())

        if "serial_numbers" in field_name:
            splitted_fieldname = field_name.split('.')
            serial_numbers = getattr(selected_device, splitted_fieldname[0])
            if getattr(serial_numbers, splitted_fieldname[1]) != value:

                signal_manager.answer_popup_received.connect(self.on_answer_received)
                signal_manager.show_popup_default.emit("info", "are you sure ?", None)
                if self.update_field_confirmed:
                    setattr(serial_numbers, splitted_fieldname[1], value)
                else:
                    return False
            else:
                return False

        else:
            if getattr(selected_device, field_name) != value:

                def on_answer_received(answer):
                    self.update_field_confirmed = answer

                signal_manager.answer_popup_received.connect(on_answer_received)
                signal_manager.show_popup_default.emit("info", "are you sure ?", None)
                if self.update_field_confirmed:
                    setattr(selected_device, field_name, value)
                else:
                    return False

        selected_device.save()

        top_left = self.index(0, 0)
        bottom_right = self.index(self.rowCount() - 1,
                                  self.columnCount() - 1)
        self.dataChanged.emit(top_left, bottom_right)
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Where in your code is `installEventFilter` being called?  Also, please show the code for the `Thread` class.

Comment: I never use installEventFilter. Thread is the built-in python threading class. the function i run in the thread is OplogWatcher.start, the OplogWatcher code is the post

Comment: Try installing your own message handler using `qInstallMsgHandler`.  Then run your code under the debugger with a breakpoint in the message handler.  That should at least allow you to get a backtrace to find out where `installEventFilter` is being called.

Comment: Actually i did (and i have no more information, no line, nothing) , this is where the trace come from (without it i have nothing just python crash)

Comment: You're mixing Qt signals with Python threads. This is not a good idea. I'd suggest switching to `QThread` first and then providing a [mcve] because a bunch of your code is not shown (for instance where is `db_signals.existing_document_updated` created?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, but i don't really understand what was wrong.

In the method : on_document_updated :
i commented the lines :

> self.beginResetModel()

and

> self.endResetModel()

with that no more crash but the view is not updated so i added a

> self.dataChanged.emit(top_left, bottom_right)

and now it's working. 
If someone understand why ? please tell me.

```
def on_document_updated(self, ns, ts, _id, mod, raw, **kw):
    old_device = None
    updated_device = None
    # self.beginResetModel()
    if len(mod) is 1: # Simple row update from this application (not necessary this instance)
        updated_device = get_mongoengine_model_from_id(_id)
        old_device = [x for x in self.devices if x.mac_adress == updated_device.mac_adress][0]
    else:  # Complete update from the database
        updated_device = get_mongoengine_model_from_pymongo_obj(mod)

        old_device = [x for x in self.devices if x.mac_adress == mod["mac_adress"]][0]
    idx = self.devices.index(old_device)
    self.devices[idx] = updated_device
    # self.endResetModel()

    top_left = self.index(0, 0)
    bottom_right = self.index(self.rowCount() - 1,
                              self.columnCount() - 1)
    self.dataChanged.emit(top_left, bottom_right)
```